# releasing tableHeaderView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

in my code i add an UIView to my tableHeaderView.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;
```

And  then i need to release or disabling this one. I tried to use

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
```

but it doesn't work, i had this error :

*malloc: *** error for object 0x4b1aff0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug*

Thank's for reading,

Tommy

Comment: if you use self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;, it should directly reflect on screen, so there is no need to do [tableView reloadData];

Comment: May be you are doing something wrong in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: How do you create `containerView`?

Comment: UIView *containerView =
    [[[UIView alloc]
      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 240)]
     autorelease];

Answer (score 1):

I got error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

I changed:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
});
```

It works for me.
Good luck!

P/s: I know this is old question:D

Answer (score 0):

The error message says your containerView is not allocated and then when you try to set the property to nil, you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
// First create the containerView
UIView *containerView = [UIView alloc] init..];

// Set it as the table header view (this will retain it)
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:containerView];

// Now we're done with containerView, so release it:
[containerView release];
```

You could have also used

```
UIView *containerView = [UIView alloc] init..] autorelease];
```

but then you wouldn't need the last release message.

If you want to "disable" this header view, it should be enough to do what you wrote:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: that what i do, but i need to release the TableHeaderView... with something like [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil]

Comment: Yep, as Raphael says, I think your problem might be somewhere else. Have you tried to use NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: it's work with self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; but not with [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];

Comment: Please try to post more relevant code. Mostly regarding how do you create tableView and containerView.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
```

and also

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

I think you may have another problem. Maybe you are releasing your containerView more than you should.

Comment: You're right !! it's work now. But i had also EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but it's another problem i think !

Comment: OK. Post you code if you need more help. T try not to use code like this:  [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 240)] autorelease];... Because I think that sometimes the autorelease is difficult to see and you can make a mistake and use a release after it... but it's just something I don't like, there is no problem